# Is it possible to create multiple run/start-up schema's in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Our solution at any given time has 2 projects that need to start up.

`Services.Host` & one other, either `Web` or `Mobile`. We often swap between projects, depending on the task required, and I'm finding it slightly "fiddly" for lack of a better word, to constantly right click on the solution, select properties, find both options and having to turn one on and another off, apply, then run.

[image]

Is there any way to save the 2 states in a separate menu item, or configuration. 
EG.

```
Run Mobile >    
   .Services.Host    
   .Mobile

Run Web >
   .Services.Host
   .Web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SwitchStartupProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571) extension allows you to configure and switch between multi-project startup configurations.

Comment: Soo close. This extension does technically solve the problem. But as a heads up to anyone using it for the same reasons as me. It doesn't look like it supports the "Multi-Device Hybrid App" project types just yet. (Which is currently only in CTP)